# How to highlight a clicked Feature Layer using ArcGIS JS API 4.x

Tags: events, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Esri recently released [version 4.0](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/index.html) of the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API, which represents a substantial re-write compared to version 3.x

Using version 3.x, a feature layer supported a long list of [events](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#events), including `click` and `mouse-over`. For example, it was easy to highlight the boundary of a polygon by listening to the feature layer's `mouse-over` event and accessing its geometry, as in this [sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=fl_hover).

Using version 4.0, the [functionality matrix](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/functionality-matrix/index.html#featurelayer) says that Mouse Events are "not planned" and that we should use [View Events](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#event:click) instead.

How can you highlight the clicked feature on a feature layer, from a view's click or hover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was answered on the Esri forums at https://geonet.esri.com/message/609517#comment-609517

```
view.on("click", function(event) {  
  view.hitTest(event.screenPoint).then(function(response) {  
    var graphics = response.results;  
    graphics.forEach(function(graphic) {  
      console.log(graphic);  
    });  
  });  
});
```

> The benefit here over how you would have done it in 3.x is that in 3.x
>   you would only get the top-most graphic that was clicked. Now you'll
>   get any graphics under the location where you clicked by using the
>   hitTest.

Answer (score 2):

The code mentioned by Stephen can be used to get the coordinates of the clicked feature, then we can use graphic class(example: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/get-started-graphics/index.html) to draw and highlight the feature.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the previous answers to this question, here is a snippet to highlight the first (top) clicked feature using the 4.x version of the API:

```
view.on("click", function(event) {  
  view.hitTest(event).then(function(response) {
      var firstLayer = response.results[0];
      var geometry = firstLayer.graphic.geometry;
      if (geometry.type === "polygon") {
        var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(
          "solid",
          new SimpleLineSymbol("solid", new Color([232,104,80]), 2),
          new Color([232,104,80,0.25])
        );
        var graphic = new Graphic(geometry, symbol);
        view.graphics.removeAll(); // make sure to remmove previous highlighted feature
        view.graphics.add(graphic);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This example should be easy to adapt to highlight other kind of geometries (just have to adjust the symbol that is applied to the graphic) or highlight other features than just the top one (iterate over each item in `response.results`).

Note that the following Esri classes should be imported with `require`:

```
require([
  "esri/Color",
  "esri/Graphic",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol"
],
  function(
      Color,
      Graphic,
      SimpleLineSymbol,
      SimpleFillSymbol
  ) {
    // code goes here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**For 3d View model of a point click highlight with circle symbol, you can use below code.**

```
view.on("click", function(event){
   view.hitTest(event.screenPoint).then(function(response) {
         var firstLayer = response.results[0];
         if(firstLayer){
         var geometry = firstLayer.graphic.geometry;
         if(geometry.type =="point"){
          var graphic = new Graphic(geometry, circleSymb);
             // make sure to remmove previous highlighted feature
             view.graphics.add(graphic);
            }
         }else{
          view.graphics.removeAll();
        }
           
    })
 });

**And The Style for this is:-** 

var circleSymb = new PointSymbol3D({
symbolLayers: [
     //wide semi-transparent icon
     new IconSymbol3DLayer({
       material: { color: [219,53,53, 0.5] },
       resource: { primitive: "circle" },
       size: 20
     }),
    //smaller opaque icon centered in transparent icon
    new IconSymbol3DLayer({
      material: { color: [219,53,53, 1] },
      resource: { primitive: "circle" },
      size: 8,
      outline: {
        color: "white",
        size: 0.5
      }
    }),
    //places an outer ring around the red icons
    new IconSymbol3DLayer({
      material: { color: [0,0,0, 0] },
      resource: { primitive: "circle" },
      size: 10,
      outline: {
        color: "black",
        size: 0.5
      }
    })
  ]    
});
```